# Allow only certain senders to an email address with Exchange?

Tags: exchange

I am going to create a helpdesk email for a department, i.e. `QChelpdesk@example.com` and they are interested in only allowing particular users to be able to send to it. I know that I can limit the address to not appearing in the address book and can easily rescrict to internal senders. How would I go about implementing a sort of filter for who can send to it. I saw this before but could not post to it. Is this example how i should proceed? Also, where exactly do I put the list of allowed senders, is it where it says $list in the third line only?

Open powershell via the exchange menu item and run those commands:

```
$list = (Get-ContentFilterConfig).BypassedSenders
$list.add("mail@domain.com")
Set-ContentFilterConfig -BypassedSenders $list
```

We run Server 2012 on an Exchange 2010.

Comment: I have an additional but very closely related question. (Near enough that I could tail it onto this question). What has changed in my situation is that I have no choice except to create a mail contact for this item instead. I dont want to entirely relay the purpose online. But a business process I am setting up requires use of an external email address that users need to see as if it were a part of our company. What comes to mind to me is to use a mail contact. I am wondering if anybody knows if mail contacts have restrict settings like what has already been discussed with DG and Mailbox?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this :

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity "QChelpdesk" -AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom @{add="user name"}
```

This example adds the user named "user name" to the list of users whose messages will be accepted by the mailbox of "QChelpdesk".

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123981(v=exchg.150).aspx
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397214%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx

Comment: OP doesn't specify whether this is a mailbox or a distribution group, but a DG has an incredibly similar method.  Set-DistributionGroup.  DGs also have a setting, AcceptMessagesOnlyFromDLMembers (Boolean), which may be of use in some cases.

Comment: @blaughw Good point! In addition, `set-mailbox` also have the `-AcceptMessagesOnlyFromDLMembers` setting

Comment: Oh, my bad.  You're totally right.  -AcceptMessagesOnlyFromDLMembers isn't a Boolean.  It's another multi valued property.  I always thought it was  a Bool that specified that only the membership of the DL can send to it.